# Move logo to right

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am trying to move logo to right but it doesn't move.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui fixed stackable borderless blue inverted menu grid">

  <div class="item three wide column">
    <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/logo.png" class="logoright">
  </div>

  <div class="item ui search eight wide column">
    <div class="ui icon input">
      <input class="prompt" placeholder="Common passwords..." type="text">
      <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logoright {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

I have also checked `ui small right floated image` and `right aligned` but no one seems to be working.

I want to move image to the left-most of search bar NOT at the end of the nav bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/n55mwbg1/1/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
.logoright {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
}
```

[Fixed jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n55mwbg1/5/)

The `!important`s are needed because your `.ui.menu .item>img:not(.ui)` selector is setting the margin and it's a more specific selector so it overrides the `.logoright` selector. If you specified an id for the img, and used that as your selector you could avoid the `!important`s completely. Might make more sense if you're only going to use this on a menu-bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for it. But don't forget to include all prefixes for different browsers support.

```css
.cont {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
        justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui fixed stackable borderless blue inverted menu grid">

  <div class="item three wide column cont">

      <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/logo.png" class="logo">

    
  </div>

  <div class="item ui search eight wide column">
    <div class="ui icon input">
      <input class="prompt" placeholder="Common passwords..." type="text">
      <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use grid for that, for example:

Comment: inside `cont` create 2 `div` with classes `two wide` or so, I'm not familiar with semantic UI

Answer (score 0):

**add this css for this**

```
 .ui.menu .item>img:not(.ui){
        border: 1px solid;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 11px;
    }
```

Comment: ok i think there is a confusion  ,  I want to move image to the left-most of search bar not at the end of the nav bar.  sorry about that

Comment: Image and the search box should come next to each other right ?

Comment: yes i gave you the html code just paste that if it will work for you

Comment: no image moves to right of the search bar but want logo to have a simple text align to right where it is right now

Comment: did you understand or should i draw a digram

Comment: How exactly you want. It's better if you draw a diagram.

Comment: i have uploded the image take a look at it

Comment: see the css i just update again it will done with this clss

Comment: i don't want to hard code it with absolute i am trying to use ui small right floated image from semantic-ui docs

Comment: but can't find it is there any oyher way to make it  and responsive to