# semantic UI - adding z index to drop down

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

my drop down gets under the right side bar i have added z index but it is not working.

```
        <div class="ui fixed stackable borderless blue inverted  menu grid">

      <div class="item three wide column ">
        <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/logo.png" class="exp">
      </div>

      <div class="item ui search six wide column">
         <div class="ui icon input">
            <input class="prompt" placeholder="Common passwords..." type="text">
            <i class="search icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="results"></div>
        </div>

      <a class="item two wide column ">menu</a>
    <div class="ui icon top item left pointing dropdown button " style="z-index: 100002 !important;">
  <i class="wrench icon"></i>
  <div class="menu  " style="z-index: 102;">
    <div class="header">Display Density</div>
    <div class="item">Comfortable</div>
    <div class="item">Cozy</div>
    <div class="item">Compact</div>
    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    <div class="item">Settings</div>
  </div>
</div>


    </div>

    <div class="ui right fixed vertical menu  header_space">
      <div class="item">
        <img class="ui mini image" src="/images/logo.png">
      </div>
      <a class="item">Features</a>
      <a class="item">Testimonials</a>
      <a class="item">Sign-in</a>
    </div>
```

take a look at the working example here https://jsfiddle.net/49eg6rh8/

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aITLm.png)

Comment: Add `position: relative` in addition to the `z-index`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/49eg6rh8/1/

Comment: I'm not sure what you want...

Comment: drop down should come above the the right bar not under it

Comment: the dropdown being the Features, testimonials, sign-in part?

Comment: no that is right side bar

Comment: So the dropdown part is supposed to display *above* the sidebar?

Comment: yes it is and it should come above

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aITLm.png  current drop down it should come above  Features, testimonials, sign-in part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you looking for?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui fixed stackable borderless blue inverted  menu grid" style="">

 <div class="item three wide column ">
  <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/logo.png" class="exp">
 </div>

 <div class="item ui search six wide column">
  <div class="ui icon input">
   <input class="prompt" placeholder="Common passwords..." type="text">
   <i class="search icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="results"></div>
 </div>

 <a class="item two wide column ">menu</a>

 <div class="ui icon top item left pointing dropdown button " style="">
  <i class="wrench icon"></i>
  <div class="menu  " style="z-index: 300;">
   <div class="header">Display Density</div>
   <div class="item">Comfortable</div>
   <div class="item">Cozy</div>
   <div class="item">Compact</div>
   <div class="ui divider"></div>
   <div class="item">Settings</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ui right fixed vertical menu  header_space" style="z-index: 100; margin-top: 50px; ">
 <div class="item">
  <img class="ui mini image" src="/images/logo.png" >
 </div>
 <a class="item">Features</a>
 <a class="item">Testimonials</a>
 <a class="item">Sign-in</a>
</div>
```

Comment: nice it worked i think you should also take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471001/move-logo-to-right